# Converting the date returned from the server to the format used by the React Date Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

APi returns the following date to me:

```js
const date = "2019-06-3021:59:59.999+00";
```

When I try to put it in `selected` in edit form:

```
  <DatePicker
     selected={date}
     onChange={this.props.handleChangeDateTask}
     showTimeSelect
     timeFormat="HH:mm"
     timeIntervals={15}
     dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
     timeCaption="time"
   />
```

returns the error `invalid time`. How  convert it to a format that React Date Picker uses? I tried `new Date (date)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You could do two things. You could use moment.js to parse date times into whatever format you want. OR you could use some functional programming to parse the data yourself. I recommend the later if you are just starting out.

Comment: @cullanrocks I used the `moment(date).toString()` but it doesn't work return me `null`

Comment: Try moment(date).toDate()

Comment: @cullanrocks moment(date).toDate() –  return me 'invalid date'

Comment: You must pass it as ISO 8601 format. To do this you must add a "T" between the data and time. Your date should look like this const date = "2019-06-30T21:59:59.999+00"; You can probably figure out how to do that yourself I assume?

Comment: @cullanrocks `moment(date).toISOString();`?

Comment: Here's what I did: 

date = date.substring(0, 10) + "T" + date.substring(10, date.length);

Answer (score 0):

The date is not in any valid format because it includes spaces between certain sections. This can be fixed using the following:

```
render(){
  const date = "2019-06-30 21: 59: 59.999 + 00"
  const formattedDate = new Date(date.replace(/: /g, ':',).replace(/ \+ /g, '+'));

  return <DatePicker
     selected={formattedDate}
     onChange={this.props.handleChangeDateTask}
     showTimeSelect
     timeFormat="HH:mm"
     timeIntervals={15}
     dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
     timeCaption="time"
   />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with moment is very easy. Parse the date to look like this

```
let date = "2019-06-30T21:59:59.999+00";
```

You can accomplish that by doing this:

```
date = date.substring(0, 10) + "T" + date.substring(10, date.length);
```

Then parse that date with moment and pass it to DatePicker:

```
return <DatePicker
     selected={moment(date).toDate()}
     onChange={this.props.handleChangeDateTask}
     showTimeSelect
     timeFormat="HH:mm"
     timeIntervals={15}
     dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
     timeCaption="time"
   />
```

Comment: Error: `date.substring is not a function`

Comment: You have to change const date to let date. And as long as date is a string (exactly as is in your question), then this WILL work. I literally just tested it, so any other issues are on you.

Comment: React date picker does not accept this format. I still have error `invalid time`. On Google Chrome works, on Mozilla firefox error